# How does the guest OS of VirtualBox get a valid dynamic IP address?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, centos, dhcp

I have install `CentOS 7` in `VirtualBox`, and want the guest `CentOS` using dynamic IP address. The network type is `bridged`.

The host `OS` is `Windows 7`, and the network information is like this:

[image]

I modified the configuration of network card of guest `CentOS`:
[image]

After executing "`service network restart`" command, and using `ip addr` to show the `IP` address:
[image]

The network and `dhcp` related logs are like this:

```
  Jun 4 01:52:40 CentOS kernel: drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
  Jun 4 01:52:40 CentOS kernel: e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
  Jun 4 01:52:41 CentOS kernel: e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
  Jun 4 01:52:41 CentOS systemd-udevd[234]: renamed network interface eth0 to enp0s3
  Jun 4 01:52:47 CentOS systemd: Starting Import network configuration from initramfs...
  Jun 4 01:52:47 CentOS systemd: Started Import network configuration from initramfs.
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS systemd: Starting Network Manager...
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager (version 1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7) is starting...
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and conf.d: 10-ibft-plugin.conf
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> WEXT support is disabled
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Acquired D-Bus service com.redhat.ifcfgrh1
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Loaded plugin ifcfg-rh: (c) 2007 - 2013 Red Hat, Inc. To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Loaded plugin iBFT: (c) 2014 Red Hat, Inc. To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2013 Red Hat, Inc. To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> parsing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo ...
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> parsing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 ...
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> read connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS systemd: Started Network Manager.
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS systemd: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (lo): link connected
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (lo): carrier is ON
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (lo): new Generic device (driver: 'unknown' ifindex: 1)
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (lo): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): carrier is OFF
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): new Ethernet device (driver: 'e1000' ifindex: 2)
  Jun 4 01:52:51 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): preparing device
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): link connected
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'enp0s3'.
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: starting connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> parsing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo ...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS network: Bringing up loopback interface: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> parsing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo ...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS network: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> parsing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo ...
  Jun 4 01:52:52 CentOS network: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> parsing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo ...
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS network: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS network: [ OK ]
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Activation (enp0s3) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> dhclient started with pid 1140
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS network: Bringing up interface enp0s3: [ OK ]
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS systemd: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS systemd: Starting Network.
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS systemd: Reached target Network.
  Jun 4 01:52:53 CentOS dhclient[1140]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x623c8c73)
  Jun 4 01:52:59 CentOS dhclient[1140]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x623c8c73)
  Jun 4 01:53:06 CentOS dhclient[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x28b9690d)
  Jun 4 01:53:13 CentOS dhclient[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x28b9690d)
  Jun 4 01:53:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:53:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:53:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:53:30 CentOS dhclient[1140]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x28b9690d)
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 request timed out.
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> timeout
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1140
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed timeout -> done
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> startup complete
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): Activation: failed for connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:53:38 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'enp0s3'.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: starting connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Activation (enp0s3) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2365
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
  Jun 4 01:53:39 CentOS dhclient[2365]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x224ada0f)
  Jun 4 01:53:42 CentOS dhclient[2365]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x224ada0f)
  Jun 4 01:53:46 CentOS dhclient[2365]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x224ada0f)
  Jun 4 01:53:54 CentOS dhclient[2365]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x1de75b49)
  Jun 4 01:54:01 CentOS dhclient[2365]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x1de75b49)
  Jun 4 01:54:10 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:54:10 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:54:10 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:54:12 CentOS dhclient[2365]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x1de75b49)
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 request timed out.
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> timeout
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2365
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed timeout -> done
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): Activation: failed for connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'enp0s3'.
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: starting connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
  Jun 4 01:54:23 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Activation (enp0s3) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2393
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
  Jun 4 01:54:24 CentOS dhclient[2393]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x77843ed1)
  Jun 4 01:54:29 CentOS dhclient[2393]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x77843ed1)
  Jun 4 01:54:41 CentOS dhclient[2393]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0xe3a3af6)
  Jun 4 01:54:45 CentOS dhclient[2393]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0xe3a3af6)
  Jun 4 01:54:50 CentOS dhclient[2393]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xe3a3af6)
  Jun 4 01:54:55 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:54:55 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:54:55 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:02 CentOS dhclient[2393]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xe3a3af6)
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 request timed out.
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> timeout
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2393
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed timeout -> done
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): Activation: failed for connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'enp0s3'.
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: starting connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
  Jun 4 01:55:08 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Activation (enp0s3) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2421
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:09 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xc0de211)
  Jun 4 01:55:12 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xc0de211)
  Jun 4 01:55:16 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPREQUEST on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xc0de211)
  Jun 4 01:55:27 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x281d5ba3)
  Jun 4 01:55:31 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x281d5ba3)
  Jun 4 01:55:34 CentOS dhclient[2425]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x3e3fe85b)
  Jun 4 01:55:38 CentOS dhclient[2425]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x3e3fe85b)
  Jun 4 01:55:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:55:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:55:39 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:41 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x281d5ba3)
  Jun 4 01:55:43 CentOS dhclient[2425]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x3e3fe85b)
  Jun 4 01:55:48 CentOS dhclient[2421]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x281d5ba3)
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 request timed out.
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> timeout
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2421
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): DHCPv4 state changed timeout -> done
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> Disabling autoconnect for connection 'enp0s3'.
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <warn> (enp0s3): Activation: failed for connection 'enp0s3'
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): Activation: Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
  Jun 4 01:55:53 CentOS NetworkManager[689]: <info> (enp0s3): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
  Jun 4 01:55:55 CentOS dhclient[2425]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x3e3fe85b)
  Jun 4 01:56:06 CentOS dhclient[2425]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x3e3fe85b)
  Jun 4 01:56:23 CentOS dhclient[2425]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x3e3fe85b)
  Jun 4 01:56:35 CentOS dhclient[2425]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
  Jun 4 01:56:35 CentOS dhclient[2425]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

The network card `enp0s3` still can't obtain a valid `IP` address. Could anyone give some clues on this issue?

Comment: Adding gateway and dns in this way is inconsistent with a dynamic address, so I suggest you remove these two statements. VirtualBox has a clear gui for setting up Bridged networking, did you follow it? If so, then perhaps you have the problem discussed an **solved** here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=37035

Comment: what happens if you manually do `dhclient enp0s3`?

Comment: @txtechhelp: I have added the logs about `dhclient enp0s3`. The system works OK when host uses ethernet cable, only failed when using wireless network.

Comment: Maybe you're on a different network via Wifi? If the network was setup via cable first, then wifi might fail.

Comment: @SPRBRN: No, only configuring one WIFI network card also has the same issue.

Comment: Start a packet sniffer on your wired network and investigate the `DHCPDISCOVER` packets. What's their source MAC address? What's your wireless NIC's MAC address?